# Create survey form in Yii2 with multiple choice answers

Tags: php, forms, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Im new to Yii, and would appreciate any help.
I need to create a page with multiple choice poll. My models look like this:

**PollQuestion:**

```
id int
title varchar
```

**PollAnswer**

```
 id char  //one letter - answer option
 title
 question_id //FK pool_question(id)
```

**PollResult**

```
user_id int
question_id int //FK poll_question(id)
answers         //will be stored like A,B,C
indicated_answer //alternaive answer specified by user
```

Sample question looks like:

```
What do you think about us?
(checkbox)A. Good  
(checkbox)B.Bad  
(checkbox)C.Other (indicate) (textbox goes here)
```

Im not sure if Im doing it right, my controller:

```
public function actionSurvey($user_id)
{
     $model = [new PollResult]; 
     foreach($model as $model_item){
         $model_item->user_id= $user_id;

         if ($model_item->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
           //only one item received, why??
        }
     }

    return $this->render('survey', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?> 
   <?php foreach(PollQuestion::find()->all() as $question) {?>
   <?php foreach($model as $model_item) { ?>

   <p><?=$question->title?></p>
   <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model_item  , "user_id"); ?>
   <?= $form->field($model_item, 'answers')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map($question->pollAnswers, 'id', 'title')?>
   <?= $form->field($model_item, 'indicated_answer') ->textInput()?>
   <?php } }?>

   <div class="form-group"> 
   <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Send'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success' ]) ?> </div> 

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The problem is that in controller i receive only one item in array. Im not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that one model entry is returned. In your form, you are creating a single model and passing that to the form.

```
public function actionSurvey($user_id)
{
     $model = [new PollResult];
       // ...
    return $this->render('survey', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

You can then expect a single model back.

Have a look at this related issue on how you can solve this.
[Utilising Yii2.0 checkboxlist for Parent-child relation models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215853/utilising-yii2-0-checkboxlist-for-parent-child-relation-models)

Comment: then how to pass array of models&

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, you need an extra form model to do that. 
You can see how to create form model on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html.

The form model you create at least has this attributes:

- answers[]
- indicated_answer[]

and you can save input from user to that attributes and save them into your ActiveRecord model.